# Selecting a datetime data and getting only the day?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

I have a datetime column in my database and want to echo out how many users regisetered today.

id | register_date

1  | 2014-04-16 09:55:13

2  | 2014-04-14 19:23:49

```
$sql_users = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result_users = mysql_query($sql_users);
```

I thought that I could check every single data in it by using date('d', $register_time ) in a while statement. Is there any easier way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use MySQL's `DATE()` and `CURDATE()` functions:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE DATE(register_date) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: If i use count i dont need to get mysql_num_rows right?